# Как сделать автозапуск minikube при включении системы ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Я новичок в kubernetes. Я заметил, что, при перезагрузке системы, minikube останавливается в virtualbox. Как можно сделать так чтобы он смог сам включаться при перезагрузке системы?

Comment: а вы пробовали через systemd добавлять unit, который будет выполнять `minikube start`?

Comment: Такой способ развертывания таким образом еще не пробовал, просто не уверен как возможно ли запустить minikube автоматически в kvm2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать systemd service:

```
$ nano /etc/systemd/system/minikube.service
[Unit]
Description=Runs minikube on startup
After=vboxautostart-service.service vboxballoonctrl-service.service vboxdrv.service vboxweb-service.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minikube start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/minikube stop
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=YOUR_CURRENT_USER
Group=YOUR_CURRENT_GROUP

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Потом `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start minikube && systemctl enable minikube`